# Docker compose Start command throwing "No volume error"

Tags: joomla-3.4, linux, docker

I am working on deploying a Joomla application on a Linux server using Docker. When I use the [docker-compose start](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/) command, I get the following error:

> "Cannot start service joomla-1: get 7bc8fef95dc63f2c845e57c3b5be68cb872179c02b0db8eeed5468e57cce1484: no such volume"

I have checked the images and available.

This was working properly before, but suddenly stopped working. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour]. Please continue to work on this issue while you wait for support.  If you uncover more clues, please edit your question to tell us.  If you manage to resolve your own issue, you are encouraged to post an educational answer on your own question.

Comment: Have you stopped all of your containers? Sounds like either the port is tied up, or the container has not exited on a previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the container Volume. Try to delete your container first and then create it again.

```
docker container prune
```

and then

```
docker-compose up
```

<sub>* this is [the accepted answer to a cross-posted question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62679912/2943403).</sub>